# Access to 2-legged-authentification forge Autodesk

Tags: php, autodesk-forge

i am trying to connect with a 2-legged-auth on forge Autodesk however since Saturday i get this response : "The requested resource does not exist". The program was working before Saturday.

If someone is aware of something on it.

Thanks

````
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate");
       
       
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
       $datas="client_id=".Viewer_config::Viewer_id."&client_secret=".Viewer_config::Viewer_secret."&grant_type=".Viewer_config::Viewer_grant."&scope=".Viewer_config::Viewer_scope;
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$datas);
   
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
           "Cache-Control: no-cache",
           "content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
       ));
    ```
````

Comment: If you get an unexpected response from an API that used to work, you should contact the API owners and ask. We're not them, nor their help desk, so we can't help you with the current status of their API.

Comment: Are you able to test it with a REST Client (Postman, Insomnia ..) ? I tested the API and the authentication is working. It's probably a problem in your code, but I'm not good in Php so I can't help you on this code.

Comment: Thanks for your helps,

this morning the response cameback.
I think that they are updating their api.

I tried contact them but got no answer yet so i came here to search information on it @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Before asking here, you always need to rule out that it's an API issue to make sure it's a code issue. So for next time, you need to do the necessary debugging before asking. We tend to know less about the services you use than you do.

Comment: Yes, you should read https://developer.api.autodesk.com documentation or should contact the API provider support team.